# Blackberry - unable to see values in debugger

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I see this when I try to inspect the value of any field in Eclipse - Method "toString" with signature "()Ljava/lang/String;" is not applicable on this object

Is it something in the settings I need to change?

Comment: Do not think it is about a setting you have missed. It is a bug in Eclipse or RIM Eclipse plugin. Use EventLogger and/or System.out.println() to log necessary code.

Comment: Agree, plugin misconfigured or bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the version of the device's software does not match the version of your simulator's software which the debugger uses.

Comment: Download a simulator with the same model and version of the device which you are debugging with, from here http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/simulators.jsp

Answer (score 1):

or else add System.out.prinln to display message you want.